# ERROR: CASE types character varying and numeric cannot be matched

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case

I am writing a select statement in Postgres which contains case statement as follows:

```
,(case when all_loc.country = 'DE' then msc_si.buyer_id else msc_si.buyer_name end) as "purchasing_group_name_buyer_name"  --story
,(case when all_loc.country = 'DE' then msc_si.planner_code else mscp.description end) as "mrp_controller_name"                --story
```

I am getting the following error. I tried with `IS` instead of `=`, didn't work. Without those two `case` statements the query runs perfectly.

> ERROR: CASE types character varying and numeric cannot be matched SQL
>   state: 42804

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I don't think it's a comparison problem, I think it's a type output problem. That is, I assume that `msc_si.buyer_name` is a string, and `msc_si.buyer_id` is a numeric.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

All the branches of a `case` expression should return the same datatype. One way to achieve that is to explicitly cast where needed:

```
,(case when all_loc.country = 'DE' then msc_si.buyer_id::varchar else msc_si.buyer_name end) as "purchasing_group_name_buyer_name"
-- Here -----------------------------------------------^
,(case when all_loc.country = 'DE' then msc_si.planner_code::varchar else mscp.description end) as "mrp_controller_name"
-- And here -----------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT "table","schema",
CASE 
WHEN  "size" <= 1024 Then SIZE::varchar || 'MB'
WHEN  "size" > 1024 AND "size"  < 1000000 Then ("SIZE"/1024)::varchar || 'GB'
WHEN  "size" > 1000000 THEN ("SIZE"/1024)/1024::varchar || 'TB'
END size
FROM SVV_TABLE_INFO 
order by 1;
```